# While executing Azure DevOps build pipeline - got the message: This pipeline needs permission to access resources before this continue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, azure-pipelines, devops

While executing the Azure DevOps Pipeline receive the Permission needed message

> This pipeline needs permission to access a resource before this run
> can continue to ......

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue update pipeline permission at the project level. Need to allow permission of: **Override check-in validation by build**. Refer the below link for more details:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#:~:text=In%20your%20project%2C%20go%20to,group%20or%20an%20individual%20user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=In%20your%20project%2C%20go%20to,group%20or%20an%20individual%20user).

Answer (score 1):

I also went through the same issue. In my case, I have added the Service connection for deployment to Azure resources through yaml pipeline. We need to allow the pipeline permission for our yaml pipeline under Security section of the Service connection. After providing the permission for my yaml pipeline, while running the pipeline, it didn't ask me for the permission message -  'This pipeline needs permission to access resources before this continue'.

Reference Link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Job screen, you will see down below a message "Permission needed":
[image]

Press the red message and you will get the following window so you can press "Permit" and it will solve it:
[image]

After doing it, it adds a new group to the permissions:
[image]